# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, uniqueidentifier

I created a table with the following attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE [a02].[property] 
(
    propertyID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newsequentialid(),
    propertyTitle VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    residenceName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    residenceStreet VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    postCode VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    bedroomCount INT NOT NULL,
    bathroomCount INT NOT NULL,
    garageCarCount INT NOT NULL,
    internalSqMetres FLOAT NOT NULL,
    outdoorSqMetres FLOAT NOT NULL,
    askingPrice FLOAT NOT NULL,
    sellingPrice FLOAT,
    registeredDate DATE NOT NULL,
    soldDate DATE,
    localityID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
            REFERENCES [a02].[locality] (localityID),
    typeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
            REFERENCES [a02].[propertyType] (typeID),
    accountID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
            REFERENCES [a02].[userAccount] (accountID)
);
```

And I'm inserting the following records:

```
INSERT INTO [a02].[property] (propertyTitle, residenceName, residenceStreet, 
                              postCode, bedroomCount, bathroomCount, garageCarCount,             
                              internalSqMetres, outdoorSqMetres, askingPrice, sellingPrice,         
                              registeredDate, soldDate, localityID, typeID, accountID)
VALUES ('Ground Floor Maisonette Fgura', '10', 'Triq il-Kbira', 
        'FGR2000', 3, 1.5, 2, 
        130, 50, 250000, 235000, 
        '11/13/2018', '11/13/2018', 
        (SELECT localityName FROM [a02].[locality] 
         WHERE localityName = 'Il-Fgura'), 
        (SELECT typeName FROM [a02].[propertyType] 
         WHERE typeName ='Maisonette'), 
        (SELECT accountID FROM [a02].[userAccount] 
         WHERE accountUsername = 'joeb')),
      ('First Floor Floor Maisonette Fgura', '10', 'Triq il-Kbira', 
       'FGR2000', 3, 1.5, 2, 
       130, 50, 350000, 335000, '11/13/2018', '11/13/2017', 
       (SELECT localityName FROM [a02].[locality] 
        WHERE localityName = 'Il-Fgura'), 
       (SELECT typeName FROM [a02].[propertyType] 
        WHERE typeName = 'Maisonette'), 
       (SELECT accountID FROM [a02].[userAccount] 
        WHERE accountUsername ='joeb')),
      ('Ground Floor Maisonette Mosta', '20', 'Triq il-Qamh', 
       'MST1000', 4, 2, 2, 
       150, 50, 275000, NULL, '11/13/2018', NULL, 
       (SELECT localityName FROM [a02].[locality] 
        WHERE localityName = 'Il-Mosta'), 
       (SELECT typeName FROM [a02].[propertyType] 
        WHERE typeName = 'Maisonette'), 
       (SELECT accountID FROM [a02].[userAccount] 
        WHERE accountUsername = 'lisaA')),
      ('Penthouse Zabbar', '5', 'Triq il-Passa',  
       'ZBR1050', 3, 1, 1, 
       150, 50, 300000, NULL, '11/13/2018', NULL, 
       (SELECT localityName FROM [a02].[locality] 
        WHERE localityName = 'Haz-Zabbar'),
       (SELECT typeName FROM [a02].[propertyType] 
        WHERE typeName = 'Penthouse'), 
       (SELECT accountID FROM [a02].[userAccount] 
        WHERE accountUsername ='joeb'));
```

I'm getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

And it marks the line :

```
INSERT INTO [a02].[property] (propertyTitle, residenceName,residenceStreet, postCode, bedroomCount, bathroomCount, garageCarCount, internalSqMetres, outdoorSqMetres, askingPrice, sellingPrice, registeredDate, soldDate, localityID, typeID, accountID)
```

Any clue what it could be?

Comment: Perhaps you have a trigger on the table that is resulting in this error.

Comment: What do you mean trigger?

Comment: Ah ye never mind.. I forgot I added another attribute.. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Use below query in the insert statement to convert the string value to uniqueidentifier.

**The string value should be >= 33. It takes only 33 characters if > 33**

```
SELECT  CAST(
        SUBSTRING(<ColName>, 1, 8) + '-' + SUBSTRING(<ColName>, 9, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(<ColName>, 13, 4) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(<ColName>, 17, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(<ColName>, 21, 12)
        AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

It will be like

```
INSERT INTO [a02].[property] (
      propertyTitle
      , residenceName
      , residenceStreet
      , postCode
      , bedroomCount
      , bathroomCount
      , garageCarCount
      , internalSqMetres
      , outdoorSqMetres
      , askingPrice
      , sellingPrice
      , registeredDate
      , soldDate
      , localityID
      , typeID
      , accountID
      )
VALUES (
      'Ground Floor Maisonette Fgura'
      , '10'
      , 'Triq il-Kbira'
      , 'FGR2000'
      , 3
      , 1.5
      , 2
      , 130
      , 50
      , 250000
      , 235000
      , '11/13/2018'
      , '11/13/2018'
      , (
            SELECT CAST(
        SUBSTRING(localityName, 1, 8) + '-' + SUBSTRING(localityName, 9, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(localityName, 13, 4) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(localityName, 17, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(localityName, 21, 12)
        AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
            FROM [a02].[locality]
            WHERE localityName = 'Il-Fgura'
            )
      , (
            SELECT CAST(
        SUBSTRING(typeName, 1, 8) + '-' + SUBSTRING(typeName, 9, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(typeName, 13, 4) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(typeName, 17, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(typeName, 21, 12)
        AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
            FROM [a02].[propertyType]
            WHERE typeName = 'Maisonette'
            )
      , (
            SELECT CAST(
        SUBSTRING(accountID, 1, 8) + '-' + SUBSTRING(accountID, 9, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(accountID, 13, 4) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(accountID, 17, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(accountID, 21, 12)
        AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
            FROM [a02].[userAccount]
            WHERE accountUsername = 'joeb'
            )
      )
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem was that, in the previous question, I had to alter the table to add a new property "Image ID"  as unique identifier FK. The thing was that I was leaving it empty, since I forgot that I altered the table. Thanks though!